# bind a promise to component in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vuejs3

App.vue

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <Header :token="token" :users="users"/>
      <router-view/>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
import Header from './components/layout/Header'
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    Header
  },
  data() { 
    return { token: null, users: [] };
  },
  created(){
    this.token = this.getToken();
    this.users = this.getUsers();
  },
  methods:{
    getToken(){
      axios.get("http://someURL.com")
        .then(res => {
          console.log("token = ", res)
          return res;
        });
    },
    getUsers(){
      axios.get("http://someURL.com")
        .then(res => {
          let users = res.data.map(({username}) => username);
            console.log("users = ", users)
            return users;
        });
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Header.vue

```
<template>
    <header class="header">
        <v-toolbar dark>
            <h1>TITLE</h1>
            
            <v-spacer></v-spacer>

            <div>
                <router-link to="/">Home</router-link> |
                <router-link to="/about">About</router-link>
            </div>
        </v-toolbar>

        <p v-if="users">{{users}}</p>
        <p v-else>No Data</p>

    </header>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name:"Header",
    props: ['token', 'users'],
    data: () => ({
    }),
    mounted(){
        this.onStart();
    },
    methods:{
        onStart(){
            console.log("insideHeader = ", this.users)
        }
    }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
    #nav{
        float: right;
    }
    .header a{
        color: #fff;
        padding-right: 5px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
</style>
```

So basically what my problem is, I am fetching some data on App.vue using axios, then binding that data on Header.vue, So when the app loads first the binded value will be undefined, only after some time the data is fetched from API. But even then the value remains undefined in Header. Any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't try to return a value from promise callback, you could use async/await to return the response :

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <Header :token="token" :users="users"/>
      <router-view/>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
import Header from './components/layout/Header'
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    Header
  },
  data() { 
    return { token: null, users: [] };
  },
  created(){
    this.token = this.getToken();
    this.users = this.getUsers();
  },
  methods:{
    async getToken(){
     let res=await axios.get("http://someURL.com")
       
          console.log("token = ", res)
          return res.data;
      
    },
   async getUsers(){
     let res=await axios.get("http://someURL.com")
       
          let users = res.data.map(({username}) => username);
            console.log("users = ", users)
            return users;
       
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Api calls are async in nature. hence make use of async/await..

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <Header :token="token" :users="users"/>
      <router-view/>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
import Header from './components/layout/Header'
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    Header
  },
  data() { 
    return { token: null, users: [] };
  },
  async created(){
    this.token = await this.getToken();
    this.users = await this.getUsers();
  },
  methods:{
    getToken(){
      return axios.get("http://someURL.com")
        .then(res => {
          console.log("token = ", res)
          return res.data;
        });
    },
    getUsers(){
      return axios.get("http://someURL.com")
        .then(res => {
          let users = res.data.map(({username}) => username);
            console.log("users = ", users)
            return users;
        });
    }
  }
};
</script>
```